# Printing all extracted emails in one text field and one activity in android app development

Tags: java, android, socrata

i succeeded in writing an android  program that extracts emails from inputted words but then the program doesnt print all the emails it found into one text field designated for it. Instead it prints the emails one after another on different screens but on the same designed activity...
        (For example; if the program found 8 emails, it would print them one after the other on different screens using the same activity, instead of printing all the 8 emails at once in a particular text field.)

**Here is the code...**

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity.
extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void
    OnExtractButtonClick(View view) {

        EditText.mainEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);
        String txt = mainEditText1.getText().toString();
        String[] words = txt.split("\\s+");


        for (String word: words) {
            if (word.contains("@")) {
                Intent intent = new.Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("word2", word);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (!txt.contains("@")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No email. address found in the document!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //How do i get all the emails found printed in one text field and on one activity.
        }
    }
}
```

forgive me, the code might not be arranged the way it should be due to the small android mobile that i am using to get my codes right.

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Did I ask a stupid question? or is my question not clear for someone to understand? I could rephrase (just say the word). Please guys, do answer my question to help my coding career as I am a newbie in java/android programming and I would love to  learn.  Thanks

Comment: You didn't tag your question properly. I submitted an edit which formats the code properly and adds `java` and `android` tags. You should always make it easy on the people trying to help you by submitting code properly formatted. It makes it far easier to spot mistakes and if you're using an IDE it shouldn't be that much of an effort :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to again work together on this. Please try this solution and let me know if it does what you need it to do. Otherwise please specify how it performs in your UI and what exactly needs to be different:

```
public void OnExtractButtonClick(View view) {

    EditText mainEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);
    String txt = mainEditText1.getText().toString();
    String[] words = txt.split("\\s+");

    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word: words) {
        if (word.contains("@")) {
            // this is where you're creating a new "screen" per message
            // Intent intent = new.Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            // intent.putExtra("word2", word);
            // startActivity(intent);

            // instead we store a word into a list if it's a match:
            resultList.add(word);
        }

        if (!txt.contains("@")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No email. address found in the document!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //How do i get all the emails found printed in one text field and on one activity.

        // create a String that displays the emails in a way you like,
        // e.g. separated by newlines:
        String result = TextUtils.join("\n", resultList);
        mainEditText1.setText(result);
    }
}
```

This uses [TextUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) which is part of Android, so it should  be available to you.

Comment: Ohhh!!!! Thank u!, I am working on it now and it seems juicy, I will let you know what's up by the time through....

Comment: Good morning oschueter,  I slept off last night that o was studying your code. But looking into it this morning I understood that .stream() is supposed to lay out all the values of word in resultList and .collect() is supposed to lay the lines of how result

Comment: Good morning oschueter, I understood that the result variable is supposed to house the Array resultList, but I receive errors when I try the code....String result = resultList.stream().collect(Collector.joining("\n")); With errors at .stream() stating it as an unknown method of  'java.util.list<java.lang.string>' , and also an error at Collector stating   it as an unknown entity. Finally I had the code prepared like this... 
               String result = resultList.stream().collect(Collector.joining("\n"));
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("word2", re

Comment: I take it you're using Java 7? I will update the solution without Java 8 features then.

Comment: I updated the answer to use Android's TextUtils instead of Java 8 streams. Let me know if this works :-)

Comment: It work, thanks. Meanwhile you are like java brain itself. What led to your this your successful knowledge. Will making project that I fancy help me through?

Comment: I've first come in touch with Java in school 8 years ago and the code I've written back then should be considered a crime against humanity :-) It takes is the will to improve aswell as lots and lots of practice. And of course: reading. You read stack traces and documentations, you read here on SO, maybe you look into successful open source projects and see how they do things. Maybe there's a Java User Group in close by your home you could attend. Just keep up the good spirits! :-)

Comment: Lol @crime against humanity. These days reading it doesn't pave the way for me but practicing, getting my hands on projects and solving it helps me big time. Anyways, its all good. Thank God I met u. Complements of the season dude

Comment: Hello Mr  Oshuetter, happy nu year bro. Please bro can you answer me this question about (Please check link) @FloatingActionButton doesnt show in the design view after setting up the design in code view